# Run update table query through all databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need the second query to run on the result of first. First query gives me all the databaseNames required for the second query

```
SELECT name 
FROM sys.databases where name like '%MySomething%'
```

And 
Second Query:

```
Update [databaseName].[someschema].[mytableSomething]
Set Flag = 1
Where Name = 'MyCondition'
```

So basically I need to update a column in a specific table in all the databases that it exists.

Comment: You'll have to write some dynamic SQL to generate and execute your second query based on the result of the first one. Google `sp_executesql`. That will get you started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Temp Table with the First Select Query, and Use While Loop through each Database name and use the Update the query with each database name in loop.

Psuedo code will be like this

```
SELECT name INTO #temprecords
FROM sys.databases where name like '%MySomething%'
```

Then use While loop

```
counter = 1
   While loop for each record in temp table until counter <= total record in temp table
    Begin
         Get Database name in for counter 1
         Update query with each database name
       counter ++
     END
```

**EDIT:-**
Your code will be like this

```
Declare @Count int, @Ini  int       
SELECT name,ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order BY database_id) as RowID
    INTO #temprecords
FROM sys.databases --where name like '%MySomething%'

SET @Count = (Select Count(*) from #temprecords)
SET @Ini = 1
While @Ini <= @Count
BEGIN
   Declare @dbname varchar(max),@qry varchar(max)
   SET @dbname = (Select name From #temprecords Where RowID = @Ini)

   SET @qry = 'Update '+ @dbname +'.[someschema].[mytableSomething]
   Set Flag = 1
   Where Name = MyCondition'

   --EXEC(@qry) --- uncomment this line one you check that @qry has correct query to update
   SET @Ini = @Ini + 1
END
```

Comment: Yea...I got the Pseudo code...but I was getting object not found errors...when I build the query

Comment: Thanks that did it. I was missing the quote...was making it more complex than it needed to be...this is simple solution...thanks